# MVC3 :: Passing an object and an HttpPostedFile in an action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I'm having problems getting an uploaded file (HTTPPostedFile) and an object posted to an action.  I have a class called widget:

```
public class Widget
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

and in the Widget controller I have an 'Add' method

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    return View();
}
```

and an overloaded method to accept what the user posts back

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Widget widget, HttpPostedFile file)
{
    // Save posted file using a unique
    // Store the path/unique name in Widget.FilePath
    // Save new Widget object
    return View();
}
```

and in the View I have the following:

```
@model Project.Models.Widget
@{
    using(Html.BeginForm())
    {
        Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)<br />
        Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)<br />
        Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)<br />
        Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)<br />
        <input type="file" id="file" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    }
}
```

What I want to do is have the user fill out the form and select a file to upload.  Once the file is uploaded, I want to save the file off using a unique name and then store the path of the file as widget.FilePath.

Each time I try, the widget object is populated, but the uploadedFile is null.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

- Make sure you have set the proper `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form, otherwise you won't be able to upload any files.
- Make sure that your file input has a `name` attribute and that the value of this attribute matches the name of your action argument. Assigning an `id` has no effect for the server side binding.

For example:

```
@model Project.Models.Widget
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)<br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)<br />
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Also make sure that your controller action works with a `HttpPostedFileBase` instead of `HttpPostedFile`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Widget widget, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    // Save posted file using a unique
    // Store the path/unique name in Widget.FilePath
    // Save new Widget object
    return View();
}
```

Also you could merge the 2 parameters into a single view model:

```
public class Widget
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Widget widget)
{
    // Save posted file using a unique
    // Store the path/unique name in Widget.FilePath
    // Save new Widget object
    return View();
}
```

Finally read the following blog post: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx

Comment: HttpPostedFileBase - that was my issue